# Let $f\left( x\right) =1 / \left( 1+x^{2}\right)$ Prove that $f$ is uniformly continous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f\left( x\right) =1 / \left( 1+x^{2}\right)$. Prove that $f$ uniformly continous.

*My proof*. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Pick $\delta=$min{$1,\varepsilon(\dfrac { ( 2+2\left| a\right| +\left| a^2\right|) \left| 1+a^2\right| } {(1+\left| a\right|)  })$}

If $\left| x-a\right|<\delta$ and $a,x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right|
=\dfrac {\left| x-a\right| \left| x+a\right| } {\left| 1+x^2\right| \left| 1+a^2\right| }$. We need to show this is smllar than $\varepsilon$.

Note that $\left| x-a\right| < 1 \Rightarrow
\left| x\right| -\left| a\right| \leq \left| x-a\right| < 1 \Rightarrow \left| x\right| < 1+\left| a\right| \Rightarrow \left| x^{2}\right|+1\leq \left| x^{2}+1\right| < 2+2\left| a\right| +\left| a^2\right|
 \Rightarrow$  Also, $\left| x\right| < 1\Rightarrow \left| x\right| < 1\Rightarrow \left| x\right|+a < 1+a \Rightarrow \left| x+a\right| < 1+\left| a\right| $.

Now, we can do this,

$\dfrac {\left| x-a\right| \left| x+a\right| } {\left| 1+x^2\right| \left| 1+a^2\right| } \leq \dfrac {\delta (1+\left| a\right|) } {( 2+2\left| a\right| +\left| a^2\right|) \left| 1+a^2\right| }\leq \varepsilon$

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: you define $\delta$ before defining $a$, that's not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use this:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right|&=&\dfrac {\left| x-a\right| \left| x+a\right| } {(1+x^2)(1+a^2)}\\
&=&\left| x-a\right|\frac{1}{1+a^2}\dfrac { \left| x+a\right| } {1+x^2}\\
&\le&\left| x-a\right|\frac{1}{1+a^2}\dfrac {|x|+|a|} {1+x^2}\\
&\le&\left| x-a\right|\frac{1}{1+a^2}(\dfrac {|x|} {1+x^2}+\dfrac {|a|} {1+x^2})\\
&\le&\left| x-a\right|\frac{1}{1+a^2}(\frac12+|a|)\\
&\le&\left| x-a\right|(\frac12+\frac{|a|}{1+a^2})\\
&\le&\left| x-a\right|(\frac12+\frac12)\\
&=&|x-a|.
\end{eqnarray}
Here $2x\le 1+x^2$ is used.

Comment: So, does my delta work?

Comment: @Kahler, $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Kahler, your $\delta$ depends on $a$.

Comment: Why $\delta$ should not depend on $a$?

Answer (score 1):

*Continuous* + *Infinitesimal* as $|x|\to +\infty$ imply *Uniformly Continuous*.

If we consider some $\varepsilon>0$, there is some interval $I=[-M,M]$ such that $|f(x)|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus I$.
 Then $f(x)$ has bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}\setminus I$, and since $I$ is a compact interval, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $I$. It follows that there is some $\delta$ ensuring 
$$ |x-y|\leq\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\leq\varepsilon.$$

Now just notice that $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is continuous and infinitesimal as $|x|\to +\infty$.